# Python - How to make a paragraph bold and red while writing into MS Word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
```

Hello!
I've tried **font.bold= True** (didnt work) in the above code line and  I was only able to create a list-bullet format, but could not make it to be bold and red. Can you kindly show me the codes please? Thanks in advance!

the whole codes, in case you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = "https://www.mei.edu/events/past-events"
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

document = Document()

heading = document.add_heading().add_run("Middle East Institute (MEI)")
heading.font.name = "Cambria"
heading.font.size = Pt(14)

events = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "feature__body boxed boxed--border")

for event in events:
    event_name = event.find("h4")
    link = event.find("a")
    try:
        print(event_name.text)
        document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
        print(link['href'])
        document.add_paragraph(link['href'])
    except:
        continue

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: "*Hello! I've tried some codes but they didn't work*" Ok, which "*codes*" would those be? Can you provide them here to illustrate your previous attempts per our [ask] guidelines?

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear how the statement `font.bold = True` fits into your broader attempt at meeting the requirements described. What is `font`? What happened when you did this (as "*didnt work*" isn't particularly descriptive)?

Comment: I put the whole code file to make it more specific. I've just seen it on Google, so I don't know what should 'font' be in this code file. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you reviewed [the docs for the `docx` library you're using](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest), specifically the [Quickstart section on *Applying bold and italic*](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#applying-bold-and-italic)?

Text formatting can only be applied at the `Run` level. You'll have to break up the code you have now just slightly to get this to work in the way you want:

```
print(event_name.text)
event_paragraph = document.add_paragraph(style='List Bullet')
event_paragraph.add_run(event_name.text).bold = True
```